# Redirecting requests over 8443 to 443

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

One of our applications was previously configured to serve SSL from tomcat over port 8443. We're migrating this application to a new environment and switching to using nginx to handle SSL termination rather than tomcat (which will operate over 8080). I would like the ability for folks to be able to connect to the new environment over 8443 but get redirected to 443 (to support anyone's old bookmarks or links).

Currently have rulesets to redirect 80 to 443, and a full ssl_certificate set defined for listening on 443, but no luck trying a variety of methods to listen on 8443 and redirect to itself over 443.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Users used to request `example.com:8443` ?

Comment: Well, there was an iptables 80 to 8080 redirect, then an 8080 to 8443 redirect. As well as a 443 to 8443 redirect. Generally, in part with the tomcat server.conf file presenting an 8443 link, users would eventually have 8443 in their URL.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but do you want 8443 to 443 or the other way?, cause I was thinking you could just do a proxy from 443 to 8443.

Comment: The answer by @cnst worked for me. Basically just needed a listener on 8443 to redirect all requests to its 443 equivalent (and 443 actually a reverse proxy to tomcat listening on 8080)

Comment: Can you please share a detailed example with a sample server.xml file. When i create another Server in server.xml, it fails to load the server.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a separate server for port 8443, and do a redirect from there.  You'd obviously still have to have a proper certificate for your 8443 server, too.

```
server {
  listen 8443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl_...;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```